# PySpark CrossValidator Fails - org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to execute user defined function

Tags: pyspark, nlp, cross-validation

I have created an ML Pipeline with PySpark, and I can fit and transform the pipeline with LogisticRegression successfully. I get a trained model.

The issue is when I try to use CrossValidate. It runs part way, and then always fails with the following error:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o1883.evaluate.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 135.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 135.0 (TID 110) (06496cbd55cf executor driver): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to execute user defined function (HasSimpleAnnotate$$Lambda$3820/0x0000000841652840: (array<array<struct<annotatorType:string,begin:int,end:int,result:string,metadata:map<string,string>,embeddings:array<float>>>>) => array<struct<annotatorType:string,begin:int,end:int,result:string,metadata:map<string,string>,embeddings:array<float>>>)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.errors.QueryExecutionErrors$.failedExecuteUserDefinedFunctionError(QueryExecutionErrors.scala:136)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.errors.QueryExecutionErrors.failedExecuteUserDefinedFunctionError(QueryExecutionErrors.scala)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:759)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
    at org.apache.spark.util.collection.ExternalSorter.insertAll(ExternalSorter.scala:197)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.SortShuffleWriter.write(SortShuffleWriter.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.ShuffleWriteProcessor.write(ShuffleWriteProcessor.scala:59)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:506)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1462)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:509)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: feature rules is not set
    at com.johnsnowlabs.nlp.serialization.Feature.$anonfun$getOrDefault$1(Feature.scala:116)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
    at com.johnsnowlabs.nlp.serialization.Feature.getOrDefault(Feature.scala:116)
    at com.johnsnowlabs.nlp.HasFeatures.$$(HasFeatures.scala:73)
    at com.johnsnowlabs.nlp.HasFeatures.$$$(HasFeatures.scala:73)
    at com.johnsnowlabs.nlp.AnnotatorModel.$$(AnnotatorModel.scala:28)
    at com.johnsnowlabs.nlp.annotators.TokenizerModel.$anonfun$tag$5(TokenizerModel.scala:340)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.nextCur(Iterator.scala:486)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:492)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:513)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:943)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:943)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1431)
    at scala.collection.generic.Growable.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.generic.Growable.$plus$plus$eq$(Growable.scala:53)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:105)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.to(TraversableOnce.scala:366)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.to$(TraversableOnce.scala:364)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.to(Iterator.scala:1431)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:358)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.toBuffer$(TraversableOnce.scala:358)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toBuffer(Iterator.scala:1431)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:345)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.toArray$(TraversableOnce.scala:339)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toArray(Iterator.scala:1431)
    at com.johnsnowlabs.nlp.annotators.TokenizerModel.$anonfun$tag$2(TokenizerModel.scala:392)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$map$1(TraversableLike.scala:286)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map(TraversableLike.scala:286)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map$(TraversableLike.scala:279)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:108)
    at com.johnsnowlabs.nlp.annotators.TokenizerModel.tag(TokenizerModel.scala:288)
    at com.johnsnowlabs.nlp.annotators.TokenizerModel.annotate(TokenizerModel.scala:400)
    at com.johnsnowlabs.nlp.HasSimpleAnnotate.$anonfun$dfAnnotate$1(HasSimpleAnnotate.scala:46)
    ... 19 more

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2454)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:2403)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:2402)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2402)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1(DAGScheduler.scala:1160)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:1160)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:1160)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2642)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2584)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2573)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:938)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2214)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2235)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2254)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2279)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$collect$1(RDD.scala:1030)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:414)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:1029)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.$anonfun$collectAsMap$1(PairRDDFunctions.scala:737)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:414)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.collectAsMap(PairRDDFunctions.scala:736)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.evaluation.MulticlassMetrics.confusions$lzycompute(MulticlassMetrics.scala:61)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.evaluation.MulticlassMetrics.confusions(MulticlassMetrics.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.evaluation.MulticlassMetrics.labelCountByClass$lzycompute(MulticlassMetrics.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.evaluation.MulticlassMetrics.labelCountByClass(MulticlassMetrics.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.evaluation.MulticlassMetrics.weightedFMeasure(MulticlassMetrics.scala:227)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.evaluation.MulticlassMetrics.weightedFMeasure$lzycompute(MulticlassMetrics.scala:235)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.evaluation.MulticlassMetrics.weightedFMeasure(MulticlassMetrics.scala:235)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.evaluation.MulticlassClassificationEvaluator.evaluate(MulticlassClassificationEvaluator.scala:153)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

I have tried to debug this, and I am stuck. If I use just my OneHotEncoder column as the 'features' vector I have no issues. It is when I add in the TFIDF vectors too that it starts to fail.

Here is my code to build the pipeline:

```
import sparknlp
spark = sparknlp.start()

from pyspark.ml.feature import HashingTF, IDF
from pyspark.ml.feature import CountVectorizer
from pyspark.ml.feature import StringIndexer
from pyspark.ml.feature import OneHotEncoder
from pyspark.ml.feature import VectorAssembler
from pyspark.ml import Pipeline


documentAssemblerTitle = DocumentAssembler().setInputCol('title').setOutputCol('titles')
documentAssemblerBody = DocumentAssembler().setInputCol('body').setOutputCol('bodies')
tokenizer_titles = Tokenizer().setInputCols(['titles']).setOutputCol('tokenized_titles')
tokenizer_bodies = Tokenizer().setInputCols(['bodies']).setOutputCol('tokenized_bodies')
stemmer_titles = Stemmer().setInputCols(['tokenized_titles']).setOutputCol('stemmed_titles')
stemmer_bodies = Stemmer().setInputCols(['tokenized_bodies']).setOutputCol('stemmed_bodies')
ngrammer_titles = NGramGenerator().setInputCols(['stemmed_titles']).setOutputCol('ngrams_titles').setN(1).setEnableCumulative(True)
ngrammer_bodies = NGramGenerator().setInputCols(['stemmed_bodies']).setOutputCol('ngrams_bodies').setN(1).setEnableCumulative(True)
finisher = Finisher().setInputCols(['ngrams_titles','ngrams_bodies'])
# tf_titles = HashingTF(inputCol='finished_stemmed_titles',outputCol='tf_features_titles')
# tf_bodies = HashingTF(inputCol='finished_stemmed_bodies',outputCol='tf_features_bodies')
tf_titles = CountVectorizer(inputCol='finished_ngrams_titles',outputCol='tf_features_titles')
tf_bodies = CountVectorizer(inputCol='finished_ngrams_bodies',outputCol='tf_features_bodies')
idf_titles = IDF(inputCol='tf_features_titles', outputCol='idf_titles',minDocFreq=5)
idf_bodies = IDF(inputCol='tf_features_bodies', outputCol='idf_bodies',minDocFreq=5)
author_indexer = StringIndexer(inputCol="author_association", outputCol="author_index")
ohe = OneHotEncoder(inputCol="author_index", outputCol="aa")
assembler = VectorAssembler(inputCols=['aa', 'idf_titles', 'idf_bodies'],outputCol='features')

pipeline_stages = [documentAssemblerTitle,
                    documentAssemblerBody,
                    tokenizer_titles,
                    tokenizer_bodies,
                    stemmer_titles,
                    stemmer_bodies,
                    ngrammer_titles,
                    ngrammer_bodies,
                    finisher,
                    tf_titles,
                    tf_bodies,
                    idf_titles,
                    idf_bodies,
                    author_indexer,
                    ohe,
                    assembler]

from pyspark.ml.classification import LogisticRegression

label_stringIdx = StringIndexer(inputCol = "Target", outputCol = "label")
pipeline_stages.append(label_stringIdx)

lr = LogisticRegression(maxIter=20)  # regParam=0.3, elasticNetParam=0.8
pipeline_stages.append(lr)

pipeline = Pipeline().setStages(pipeline_stages)
pipeline_stages
```

Here is the code for the cross-validation:

```
from pyspark.ml.evaluation import MulticlassClassificationEvaluator, BinaryClassificationEvaluator
from pyspark.ml.tuning import TrainValidationSplit, CrossValidator, ParamGridBuilder
import numpy as np

# pipeline = Pipeline().setStages(pipeline_stages)
paramGrid_lr = ParamGridBuilder().addGrid(lr.maxIter, [1,2]).build()
# paramGrid_lr = ParamGridBuilder() \
#     .addGrid(lr.regParam, [0.01, 0.5, 1]) \
#     .addGrid(lr.elasticNetParam, [0.0, 0.5, 1]) \
#     .addGrid(model.maxIter, [10, 20]) \
#     .addGrid(idf.numFeatures, [10, 100, 1000]) \
#     .build()
# evaluator = BinaryClassificationEvaluator()
evaluator = MulticlassClassificationEvaluator()
cv = TrainValidationSplit(estimator=pipeline,
                    estimatorParamMaps=paramGrid_lr,
                    evaluator=evaluator)

cvModel = cv.fit(train)
```

And my preprocessing code:

```
import re
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf

@udf("String")
def strip_text(text):
  if text is not None:
    stripped = text.lower()    

    # remove all headings, bold text, and HTML comments from the Markdown text.
    # These items have all been used by the React team in their issue templates on GitHub
    headings_pattern = r'(<=\s|^)#{1,6}(.*?)$'
    bold_pattern = r'\*\*(.+?)\*\*(?!\*)'
    comments_pattern = r'<!--((.|\n)*?)-->'
    combined_pattern = r'|'.join((headings_pattern, bold_pattern, comments_pattern))

    stripped = re.sub(combined_pattern, '', stripped)

    # find all URLs in the string, and then remove the final directory from each to leave the general URL form
    # there may be useful patterns based on what URLs issues are commonly linking to
    url_pattern = re.compile(r'(https?://[^\s]+)')
    for url in re.findall(url_pattern, stripped):
        new_url = url.rsplit("/", 1)[0]
        stripped = stripped.replace(url, new_url)

    non_alpha_pattern = r'[^A-Za-z ]+'
    stripped = re.sub(non_alpha_pattern, '', stripped)    
    
    return ' '.join(stripped.split())
  else:
    return " "

from pyspark.sql.functions import col
train = train.withColumn("body", strip_text(col("body"))).withColumn("title", strip_text(col("title")))
validation = validation.withColumn("body", strip_text(col("body"))).withColumn("title", strip_text(col("title")))
```

Thanks for any help you may be able to provide. I have been working on this with no progress for a long time now.

I have tried removing my pre-processing UDF, but there was no difference.

I have tried to impute null values as I saw this could potentially be an issue, but it doesn't fix it

```
train = train.fillna(0)
```

I have tried removing the IDF text features altogether just leaving the OneHotEncoded column, and this did work. So I believe it is an issue with the text column, but I am not sure what to do next.

Comment: If anyone comes across this in the future, this is apparently a bug, an incompatibility between the two libraries.

https://github.com/JohnSnowLabs/spark-nlp/issues/1158